# update content-type

Tags: content-type

I've got a simple question, but don't know how to solve the problem.
What's the best way to update an already deployed content-type? I want to keep the lists, that already use my old one, but need to update it.

Comment: Did you create the content type in the browser or was this created and deployed via feature?

Comment: And what do you want to update? Only add a field or ?

Comment: I deployed it as a feature and I changed the form templates. Now I want the already created forms to use the new template. So i need to "redeploy" the content-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to implement a custom rendering template, so didn't realy need to redeploy it as I learned now. The best way to achieve this was to use an event receiver to update the existing content-type "on the fly". Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Feature Versioning. See [Deep dive into feature versioning and upgrade support in SharePoint 2010](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/Podcasts/Pages/SPWebCast%20019%20-%20Deep%20dive%20into%20feature%20versioning%20and%20upgrade%20support%20in%20SharePoint%202010.aspx).